# Writing in pure 1's and 0's

Tags: performance, binary

I have been wondering about writing code in pure binary.  I realize that this is completely impractical, as well as extremely hard.  I have codded some in a few languages but for some reason the thought of being able to write pure binary seems intriguing.  Can you hepl explain the basics of this?  I have researched but all the answers are "this is not practical" even though that is obvious and the point is to see the limits of programmers and binary.  If their would be a link to a IDE or tutorial to teach some of this it would be awesome.  My point is more to understand how it works, not to make big programs but it would be nice to be able to create some extremely basic ones.  I think it would be nice to make a very high performance program.

Comment: Optimisation would be the opposite of easy.

Comment: Given that your spelling is less than exemplary, your chances of programming in binary are limited.

Comment: ok yes, you are correct but i would still be much more happy id you  would answer my question

Comment: @MikeW: There is... "Is their a tutorial or even IDE on the basics of this?"  Unfortunately, we also don't allow questions asking for tutorials.

Comment: I think you may want to learn assembly.  Trying to do anything in binary is, to use a poor word, illogical.  Assembly is about as low level as a human can practically go.  If you even could write "in binary", it'd be so unreadable and time consuming, there would be no value.   Optimization would not be "very easy".

Comment: ok then I will ask could you explain the basics

Comment: I will mention that my EE microcontrollers class included writing some machine code.  We used hex, not binary, but still working directly with the raw machine code.  It was for Motorola's HC11 family of processors, which has a simple instruction set with strong patterns (five addressing modes, IIRC)

Comment: Use Google, not Stack Overflow:  https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=arduino+assembly+tutorial&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: what i mean by that is it would be very quick because it would not have to convert into a lower language

Comment: i meant performance not optomization

Comment: You do realize that translation of many high level languages into machine code occurs only once, when the code is written, and therefore doesn't slow down execution?  This process is called *compilation*.

Comment: yes, but their is also languages like python with an interpreter that are much slower due to this

Comment: and if nothing else, couls you help explain how the conversio process is made and such?

Comment: I guess that this is impossible.  uhh well assembly it is.

Comment: machine code is lower though, and would that be a viable option?

Comment: It is not lower.  There is (essentially) a 1:1 mapping between assembler and the raw binary opcodes.

Comment: Oh u am mistaken ok then which do you recommend and what is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but not particularly easy.

To do it, you normally start by writing the code in assembly language, typically on paper. You then use an encoding table to assemble that data by hand. Finally, you use a debugger or "monitor" program to enter the binary into RAM. Usually you want to save it to a file before running it (to avoid re-entering it if, for example, it crashes).

There is one major caveat though: it's really only even close to practical on systems that support some sort of executable file format that has little or no overhead. For one example, under MS-DOS you typically did this with a .com file, which is pretty much just raw binary. What you put into the file gets loaded at an offset of 0x100, and execution starts at the beginning.

When you get to something like Windows with PE format executables or Linux with ELF format, it's a whole different story. I'd say about the only halfway reasonable way to do the job under these would be to write a shell program using some existing linker to produce the executable file, and have it allocate some memory, load code from your file into it, and then execute a jump to your code to start execution. Trying to encode a PE or ELF header by hand would be pretty dire, to put it mildly.

Comment: but is their not a difference in machine code vs binary? even if machine code and assemble map to each other, their is a difference between 1 and 0s and machine cod right?

Comment: @RyanCobourn: No--machine code is the binary code that's directly executed by the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some binary/machine code and the corresponding assembly code:

```
Machine code     Assembly code
03 45 84         add 0xffffff84(%ebp),%eax
83 c0 30         add $0x30, %eax
f7 e2            mul %edx
```

Notice there is a 1-1 correspondence between an assembly instructions and the corresponding machine code.  (The instruction lengths differ because this is x86 code).

Because binary code and pure assembly code map to one another, there is no difference in speed between the two.

In practice, the only people who program in hex are those that don't have access to an assembler or people who like to solve problems the (really) hard way.